# Отключение аппаратных кнопок Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Всем привет, ребят помогите пожалуйста не могу разобраться как мне заблокировать нажатие кнопки "Home" "Overview" "Back"
На кнопку назад я повесил событие :

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        val alertBuild = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        alertBuild.setMessage("Вы действительно хотите выйти?")
        alertBuild.setPositiveButton("Да") { dialog, which ->
            onPause()
        }
        alertBuild.setNegativeButton("Нет", null)
        alertBuild.show()
    }
```

На остальные кнопки не понимаю как реализовать пробовал так

```
override fun onUserLeaveHint() {

        val alertBuild = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        alertBuild.setMessage("Вы действительно хотите выйти?")
        alertBuild.setPositiveButton("Да") { dialog, which ->
            onPause()
        }
        alertBuild.setNegativeButton("Нет", null)
        alertBuild.show()
        super.onUserLeaveHint()
    }

    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            onPause()
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    override fun onKeyLongPress(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            onPause()
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Но ничего не помогает. Помогите пожалуйста кто реализовывал подобные вещи противоречащие правилам гугла. Спасибо

Comment: Если бы была возможность переопределить базовые кнопки, то можно было написать такое приложение, из которого пользователь не смог бы выйти. Поэтому такой возможности нет. Только если ваш телефон не рутован.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос. Есть ли root-права на вашем телефоне?